Freezing/Unfreezing Layers in Keras
I am fine-tuning a convnet model with Keras (VGG16) and I am playing around with it.
To freeze all layers except the last 3 layers, I am unfreezing all layers, then I freeze all layers again except the last three.
conv_base.trainable = True
for layer in conv_base.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

This does the job correctly.
If I use the opposite logic, which is freezing only the last three layers without touching the other layers, it doesn't work!
for layer in conv_base.layers[-3:]:
    layer.trainable = True

Can anyone explain the trick?
Best

Why would the second option work? You are not freezing anything...

It's frozen beforehand in both cases. I am asking about the opposite.

I still don't get it. You are talking about "freezing only the last three layers" and yet you are setting their trainable argument to True, which is NOT freezing them.

I don't see any difference.
import tensorflow as tf

conv_base = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights=None)

conv_base.trainable = True
for layer in conv_base.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in conv_base.layers:
    print(int(layer.trainable), end='')

print()

conv_base.trainable = False
for layer in conv_base.layers[-4:]:
    layer.trainable = True

for layer in conv_base.layers:
    print(int(layer.trainable), end='')

Result:
00000000000000000001111
00000000000000000001111

the only thing I changed was the index [-4:] (instead of [-3:]) in the second case.
